# How to draw a rubber band line on a Google Map (preferably with PrimeFaces)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf-2, primefaces

I found this link for drawing a rectangle on a google map and was able to make it work as a test just using the raw google map code.
[Google map rectangle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JsAJA/3/)

However, it really does not fit into what I am trying to do.

I am using the PrimeFaces  component to draw the map and handle the events, etc.
Currently, I have a map where the user can draw a polygon by clicking on a map position to add a marker, then clicking on another map position to add another marker, then I add a polyline between the points and subsequent points to create the polygon on the map.

There are two problems with this;
1) There is no connection between the points until after the latest marker is dropped.
2) You have to do a map refresh to draw the polyline after every new point selection.

What I would like to do is create an anchor point with the first marker and then do a rubber band draw to the next point by dragging the mouse, and continue to the rest of the points.

The example I found shows how to draw a rectangle on a raw google map, and I was hoping to use this as a model.  The problem is that there appears to be a rectangle rubber band in the google api, but I have not found a rubber band line in that api.

Has anyone done this before in the context of PrimeFaces  component?
That is what I am really looking for.
I would be happy to find a javascript example of a rubber band line on a google map if nothing else.

Thanks.